# Multiple Passenger Installations

Tags: macos-big-sur, passenger-nginx

How can I find which `passenger` installation is bad and delete it?  `Passenger` troubleshooting has resulted in a warning of multiple installations, but the feedback integrates both of them somehow.  Latest versions on `Big-Sur`.

```
Passenger installation test:

 * Checking whether this Passenger install is in PATH... ✓
 * Checking whether there are no other Passenger installations... (!)

   You are currently validating against Phusion Passenger 6.0.7, located in:

     /opt/homebrew/Cellar/passenger/6.0.7_5/libexec/bin/passenger

   Besides this Passenger installation, the following other
   Passenger installations have also been detected:

     /opt/homebrew/bin/passenger

   Please uninstall these other Passenger installations to avoid
   confusion or conflicts.


Detected 0 error(s), 1 warning(s).

~ ❯ which passenger
/opt/homebrew/bin/passenger
~ ❯ passenger -v
Phusion Passenger 6.0.7


~ ❯ brew info passenger

passenger: stable 6.0.7 (bottled), HEAD
Server for Ruby, Python, and Node.js apps via Apache/NGINX
https://www.phusionpassenger.com/
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/passenger/6.0.7_5 (4,567 files, 288.6MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2021-03-30 at 12:55:05
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/passenger.rb
License: MIT
==> Dependencies
Build: nginx ✔
Required: openssl@1.1 ✔, pcre ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
  Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
To activate Phusion Passenger for Nginx, run:
  brew install nginx
And add the following to /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/nginx.conf at the top scope (outside http{}):
  load_module /opt/homebrew/opt/passenger/libexec/modules/ngx_http_passenger_module.so;
And add the following to /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/nginx.conf in the http scope:
  passenger_root /opt/homebrew/opt/passenger/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
  passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

To activate Phusion Passenger for Apache, create /etc/apache2/other/passenger.conf:
  LoadModule passenger_module /opt/homebrew/opt/passenger/libexec/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
  PassengerRoot /opt/homebrew/opt/passenger/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/locations.ini
  PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/bin/ruby
==> Analytics
install: 593 (30 days), 1,494 (90 days), 6,255 (365 days)
install-on-request: 548 (30 days), 1,399 (90 days), 5,473 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)
```